# Unable to access external location in Databricks on AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm unable to access one particular external location in Databricks on
AWS using the databricks cli

```
databricks unity-catalog external-locations get --name <name>
```

returns

```
Error: Authorization failed. Your token may be expired or lack the valid scope
```

This external location is in an S3 bucket and my user has ALL PRIVILEGES for the storage credential

```
SHOW GRANTS `username` ON STORAGE CREDENTIAL `sc-name`;
```

From a databricks notebook I'm able to query the tables in the catalog using the external location

```
USE CATALOG `catalog-name`;
USE SCHEMA schema-name;
select * from table-name;
```

Using the databricks cli, I'm able to access other external locations in this workspace that are pointing to different buckets. These external locations have similar IAM role and policy associated with them, just with different S3 resource names. Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Since it works for other external locations, then the issue is probably related to permissions. Check the permissions on the External Location in the Unity Catalog interface.

Comment: I don't see it listed in the Unity Catalog interface. My user is an admin user though